# Capturing Screenshot in When when Face is detected

Tags: python, opencv

i Have to make a code that caputres screenshot when a face is detected in a video so that the image can be used for image recognition dataset

i made a program that captures all frames but i need to make it capture only when a face is detected

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
count = 0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('window-name',frame)
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
        count = count + 1
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # destroy all the opened windows
```

Comment: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html

Comment: i need help with the code tried but its not working

Comment: post your full attempt then

Comment: Full Code Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code and it has 1 small mistake. You don't specify the XML classifier path correctly. I fixed the path using full path where the XML file is located and works successfully.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # I tried using webcam and works
count = 0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('window-name',frame)
    # Below you have to insert the full path of XML file, below is mine
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/ProgramData/Anaconda2/pkgs/opencv-3.2.0-np111py27_0/Library/etc/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
        count = count + 1
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # destroy all the opened windows
```